# jquery dialog box not showing scrollbar in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, dialog, scroll

I'm having a small issue with a jquery dialog box.

It works just fine in all browsers except one, I bet you can guess which one.

When it initially loads the dialog box it doesn't show the scroll bar and isn't sized as specified in the code.

When you go and find the bottom right corner to resize the dialog, the second you click and move it, it goes to the size as per the code and now has the scroll bar.

```
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    height: 100,
    maxHeight: 500,
    width: 800,     
    modal: true,
    buttons: {...
```

Another odd thing, if I don't set the height to 100, it will show the scroll bar but the height of the dialog box does not start at the maxHeight and grows off the screen.
Any help in being able to prevent the height from growing past the maxHeight and having the scroll bars show from the start is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the issue? My guess is that there is an issue with the dimension of your container. Or maybe you need to try overflow:hidden. Also some more code would help. (ie) The html structure you are using and any corresponding CSS.

Comment: maxHeight is supposed to be the maximum height it can be resized. Maybe you are looking for minHeight? height should work though.

Comment: IE 8
The HTML structure is pretty basic, no DIVs inside DIVs or anything
<div id="dialog-form" title="Material Selection/Measurement Required">
 <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

</div>

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/PGK73) to see screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was stupid quirks mode that was the problem.
I put in

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

before my `<html>` and everything works as is all other browsers.